# How to find the index which matches the specfic value of IEnuemerable value using Linq in C#?

Tags: linq, ienumerable, selectedindex

Basically I write down small app in WPF C# for serial port.

For my initial settings of serial port when the specific port number is chosen from ComPortComboBox , it should display the correct port settings (eg: BaudRate) of the specific port which has been chosen.

So I decided to assign the SelectedIndex of the BaudRateComboBox when the port number gets changed.

So I am trying to read the baud rate of the selected port then match the baud rate value with the values defined in BaudRateComboBox to locate the correct index using Linq query of C#. I know we have foreach method to locate the index but I would like to learn and apply Linq in c# as a solution.

Please refer to the code for further understanding. I need to add my Linq in ComPort_SelectionChanged method to locate the index which match with the condition.

```
namespace SerialReadAndWrite
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private SerialPort m_port = new SerialPort();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ComPort_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
            ComPortComboBox.ItemsSource = ports;
        }

        private void ComPort_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_port.PortName = ComPortComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString();
            //BaudRateComboBox.SelectedIndex= choose the index from BaudRateComboBox.ItemSource which matches the value of the existing settings of the port
            BaudRateComboBox.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        private void BaudRate_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            m_port.BaudRate = Convert.ToInt32(BaudRateComboBox.SelectedItem.ToString());         
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note sure LINQ is your best choice, depending on the actual type of `BaudRateComboBox.ItemSource`, but you can use the two parameter version of `Select` to find a match:

```
BaudRateComboBox.SelectedIndex = BaudRateComboBox.ItemSource.Select((br,n) => new { br, n }).First(brn => brn.br == m_port.BaudRate).n;
```

I assume your `ItemSource` is a collection of `Int32` to match `BaudRate`, if not, add an appropriate conversion.